# How to declare cross referenced class types?

Tags: delphi, oop, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

I tried to construct a class system in Delphi. The classes `TFieldSpec` and `TTableSpec` refer to each other through object properties.

```
type
  TFieldSpec=class(Tobject)
  private
    FTableSpec : TTableSpec;
  public
    property TableSpec : TTableSpec read FTableSpec;
  end;

  TTableSpec=class(Tobject)
  private
    FFields : array[1..100] of TFieldSpec;
  end;
```

When I compile this, I get this error:

```
[Error] Objects.pas(66): Undeclared identifier: 'TTableSpec'
```

How to construct these class types?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use forward declaration of `TTableSpec`:

```
type
  TTableSpec = class;

  TFieldSpec=class(Tobject)
  private
    ..
    FTableSpec : TTableSpec;
    ..
  end;

  TTableSpec=class(Tobject)
  private
    FName : string;
    ..
  end;
```

Comment: ... and the forward declaration needs to be declared in the same "type" declaration